# Image source not found in images content element

Tags: html, image, typo3, src

This is an extract of the rendered code of the frontend.

```
<div style="width: 345px;" class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
  <ul>
    <li style="width: 0px;" class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-firstcol">
      <img width="" height="" border="0" alt="" src="">
    </li>
    <li style="width: 335px;" class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-lastcol">
     <img width="335" height="381" border="0" alt="" src="uploads/pics/katze_start_01.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The first `<li><img>` contains no src, height, width, alt, etc. In the backend there is a image and it should work. Well I use the standard CSS Styled Content Framework and render the content elements via styles.content.getLeft (does work). For some reason (it feels not logical) it does not render the first image of an "image" content element...

What is the error here?

Comment: Does it never render the first image, or is it just with this specific content element?

Comment: It does never render the first image.

Comment: Are you using something to render/scale images like ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in install tool if imagemagick/graphicsmagic works. There are five tests defined in "Image Processing".

If everything works fine there, check if your image has special chars (f.e. german umlauts) or spaces in there. Replace spaces (i guess you uploaded them via scp/ftp, via TYPO3 they should be replaced automatically) and check install tool options "[SYS][UTF8filesystem]" and "[SYS][systemLocale]" in section "All Configuration".

Comment: Ja. Fein fein! Das worked.
Yes the image processing doesnt work because our mac is a PowerPC which can not handle the image magick applications. Our online server can handle those applications and the image does work fine on them.